# Evaluate the series $\sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \binom{4+x}{x} \frac{1}{2^x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to find the value of

$$\sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \binom{4+x}{x} \frac{1}{2^x}$$

and using the formula for $\binom{n}{r}$, I have simplified it to

$$\sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x+4)(x+3)(x+2)(x+1)}{24\cdot 2^x}$$

but I have no idea how to proceed. It's question 9 from this link:
https://www.nanomath.org/sample.pdf

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to type math](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in this site. I suggest you try and edit your question to fix it. Otherwise, many users won't even read your question.

Comment: The generalized binomial theorem will give you the answer. Look it up.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worthwhile to know this identity that often is useful for these kind of questions-
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{k+n-1}{k} {x^k}=(1-x)^{-n}$$
An application of this directly gives you an answer.

Try proving this as an exercise. I will help you if you can't.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: Evaluate $\sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \binom{4+x}{x} \frac{1}{2^x}$

Let $$S(n) = \sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+x}{x} \frac{1}{2^x}$$

So we have $$S(4) = \sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \binom{4+x}{x} \frac{1}{2^x}$$

$$S(3) = \sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \binom{3+x}{x} \frac{1}{2^x}$$

$$S(4) - S(3) = \sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \left(\binom{4+x}{x} - \binom{3+x}{x}\right) \frac{1}{2^x}$$

$$ = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{x=1}^{\infty} \binom{3+x}{x-1} \frac{1}{2^{x-1
}}$$

$$ = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \binom{4+x}{x} \frac{1}{2^x} =\frac{S(4)}{2}$$ by change of variable.

So $S(4) = 2S(3) = 4S(2) = 8S(1) = 16S(0)$ where

$$S(0) = \sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \binom{0+x}{x} \frac{1}{2^x} = 2$$

So $$S(4) = 32$$

Comment: I am sure the method is right. So go ahead. Vote down.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious, your answer does actually look right... Maybe other users didn't like your weird omission of the dummy variable $x$ in your sum notation? You also mysteriously started using $y$ instead of $x$ in your second to last sum (a typo?). I have edited your answer to fix these things (hopefully to your liking).$\tag*{}$I understand that some users don't like to out themselves as downvoters, but in this situation, I don't understand why they wouldn't just tell you what they found wrong with your answer, and let you fix it.

Comment: The answer looks absolutely right (+1).

Comment: Ok, I see the big issue now. You might want to make it more clear that your calculations work for general $n$ rather than just for $n=4$ (so you can then recursively relate the value of $S(4)$ to $S(0)$ like you do). Modifying the math section right after "so we have" to just prove $S(n)-S(n-1)=\frac{S(n)}{2}$ would save this answer for me. Edit your answer to do this, and I'll give it a (+1).